# Limit but not Order in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I meet one problem while I using `Limit` in PIG.

The result of `Limit` is sorted, but I don't want the result be sorted.

From the example on the website:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);

DUMP A;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
(8,4,3)
```

Using `Limit`

```
X = LIMIT A 3;

DUMP X;
(1,2,3)
(4,3,3)
(7,2,5)
```

Is it possible that show the top 3 lines without sorted in the reuslt?

```
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
```

My code is below:

```
A = LOAD '$input';
B = foreach A generate $s_field;
C = FILTER B BY $pattern;
D = FOREACH C {
            topnresult = LIMIT B $lines;
            GENERATE FLATTEN(topnresult);
        }
dump D;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What version you using pig and hadoop?

Comment: can you paste your sample data and pig script?

Answer (score 1):

By default LIMIT  will execute **ORDER** command followed by **LIMIT** command internally, so obviously you will get the sorted list. There are many way to solve this problem, one option could be

**input.txt**

```
1       2       3
4       2       1
8       3       4
4       3       3
7       2       5
8       4       3
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
B = RANK A;
C = FILTER B BY rank_A<=3;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE a1,a2,a3;
DUMP D;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
```

**Option2:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B {
                top3list =  LIMIT A 3;
                GENERATE FLATTEN(top3list);
              }
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
(8,3,4)
```

**UPDATE: Solution1**

```
A = LOAD '$input';
B = foreach A generate $s_field;
C = FILTER B BY $pattern;
D = GROUP C ALL;
E = FOREACH D {
            topnresult = LIMIT C $lines;
            GENERATE FLATTEN(topnresult);
        }
DUMP E;
```

**Solution2:**

```
A = LOAD '$input';
B = foreach A generate $s_field;
C = FILTER B BY $pattern;
D = RANK C;
E = FILTER D BY rank_C<=$lines;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE $1..;
DUMP F;
```

I have tested the solution using the below command line and its working fine

```
>pig -x local -param input='input.txt' -param s_field='$0,$1,$2' -param pattern='$0<10' -param lines=3 myscript.pig
```

Comment: can you paste your pig script?

Comment: The reason is you are mixing the two solutions, please go ahead with any one solution. You can't use nested FOREACH after filter stmt, bcoz nested foreach will work only with bags. Please Update  your sample input data format and values of $s_field,$pattern. I will help you to get the result.

Comment: Is it possible that revise nothing and get the result?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for lately reply. It's seems the result is sorted by another criteria but I don't understand the sorted method. There are 2 attribute in my program, one is show only top n lines/results, and the other is show all. For the "show all" attribute, I used `LIMIT C 999999999` to show all result. Is it the correct way to do this? Can we use wildcard such as `LIMIT C *` in PIG? From the result, suppose the results are same in the beginning in both attribute (top n and show all), isn't it?

Comment: What is the sorting criteria for LIMIT?